# Uniswap DAI / ETH: TypeError: exchangeContract.methods.getEthToTokenInputPrice is not a function

Tags: contract-development, javascript, etherscan, uniswap, dai

I played around with this https://github.com/dappuniversity/trading-bot and came to the following error: TypeError: exchangeContract.methods.getEthToTokenInputPrice is not a function

I thought that the Error appears becuase I am using the wrong contract but after testing different contracts on the goerli and mainnet network it's still not working.

These are the contracts I set (mainnet):

```
// DAI
const DAI_ABI = [{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"chainId_","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"src","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"guy","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":true,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"bytes4","name":"sig","type":"bytes4"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"usr","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"bytes32","name":"arg1","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"bytes32","name":"arg2","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"bytes","name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"LogNote","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"src","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"dst","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"DOMAIN_SEPARATOR","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"PERMIT_TYPEHASH","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"usr","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"usr","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"burn","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint8","name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"guy","type":"address"}],"name":"deny","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"usr","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mint","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"src","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"dst","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"move","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"nonces","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"holder","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"nonce","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"expiry","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"allowed","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"permit","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"usr","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"pull","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"usr","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"push","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"guy","type":"address"}],"name":"rely","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"dst","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"src","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"dst","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"version","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"wards","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]
const DAI_ADDRESS = '0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F'
const daiContract = new web3.eth.Contract(DAI_ABI, DAI_ADDRESS);

// Uniswap Dai Exchange: https://etherscan.io/address/0xef1c6e67703c7bd7107eed8303fbe6ec2554bf6b
const EXCHANGE_ABI = [{"inputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"permit2","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"weth9","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"seaport","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"nftxZap","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"x2y2","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"foundation","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"sudoswap","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"nft20Zap","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"cryptopunks","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"looksRare","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"routerRewardsDistributor","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"looksRareRewardsDistributor","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"looksRareToken","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"v2Factory","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"v3Factory","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"pairInitCodeHash","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"poolInitCodeHash","type":"bytes32"}],"internalType":"struct RouterParameters","name":"params","type":"tuple"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"inputs":[],"name":"ContractLocked","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"ETHNotAccepted","type":"error"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"commandIndex","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"message","type":"bytes"}],"name":"ExecutionFailed","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"FromAddressIsNotOwner","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InsufficientETH","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InsufficientToken","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidBips","type":"error"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"commandType","type":"uint256"}],"name":"InvalidCommandType","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidOwnerERC1155","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidOwnerERC721","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidPath","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidReserves","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"LengthMismatch","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"NoSlice","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"SliceOutOfBounds","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"SliceOverflow","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"ToAddressOutOfBounds","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"ToAddressOverflow","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"ToUint24OutOfBounds","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"ToUint24Overflow","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"TransactionDeadlinePassed","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"UnableToClaim","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"UnsafeCast","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V2InvalidPath","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V2TooLittleReceived","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V2TooMuchRequested","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V3InvalidAmountOut","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V3InvalidCaller","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V3InvalidSwap","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V3TooLittleReceived","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V3TooMuchRequested","type":"error"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"RewardsSent","type":"event"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"looksRareClaim","type":"bytes"}],"name":"collectRewards","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"commands","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"bytes[]","name":"inputs","type":"bytes[]"}],"name":"execute","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"commands","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"bytes[]","name":"inputs","type":"bytes[]"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"execute","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"","type":"uint256[]"},{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"","type":"uint256[]"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"}],"name":"onERC1155BatchReceived","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes4","name":"","type":"bytes4"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"}],"name":"onERC1155Received","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes4","name":"","type":"bytes4"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"}],"name":"onERC721Received","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes4","name":"","type":"bytes4"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes4","name":"interfaceId","type":"bytes4"}],"name":"supportsInterface","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"int256","name":"amount0Delta","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"int256","name":"amount1Delta","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"uniswapV3SwapCallback","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"stateMutability":"payable","type":"receive"}]
const EXCHANGE_ADDRESS = '0xef1c6e67703c7bd7107eed8303fbe6ec2554bf6b'
const exchangeContract = new web3.eth.Contract(EXCHANGE_ABI, EXCHANGE_ADDRESS);
```

And this is the line the error occures:

```
// Check Eth Price
    const daiAmount = await exchangeContract.methods.getEthToTokenInputPrice(ETH_AMOUNT).call()
    const price = web3.utils.fromWei(daiAmount.toString(), 'Ether')
```

I also tried it with the DAI / ETH Pool contract as exchange but that also didn't work: https://info.uniswap.org/#/pools/0x60594a405d53811d3bc4766596efd80fd545a270

If anyone could tell me the right Contrct data or if the code is the problem I would be extremely grateful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getEthToTokenInputPrice` is a method only available on uniswap v1's [exchange contract](https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v1/reference/exchange).

For DAI and Eth, the exchange's address is [0x2a1530C4C41db0B0b2bB646CB5Eb1A67b7158667](https://etherscan.io/address/0x2a1530C4C41db0B0b2bB646CB5Eb1A67b7158667#readContract).

Uniswap V1 is not the most popular Dex now. If you are interested in working with V2 and V3, you can go to their factory contract([V2](https://etherscan.io/address/0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f), [V3](https://etherscan.io/address/0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984#readContract)) and call their `getPair` or `getPool` method to find the addresses of token exchange/pair/pool.

Hope that helps, happy coding.

Comment: Thank you so much!